# Webcam old vaio not detected

Tags: webcam

I'm runnin ubuntu on a VGN-CR150F and my webcam is not detected. I'm not sure if there's a way to work this out. I've seen many solutions for different vaio versions but not for mine.

Thanks

Comment: Often different models will use the same chipset as a similar model. You might try a solution for a Vaio with a similar model number. Can you find the webcam info in `sudo lshw` or `lsusb`?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to install the driver using WINE? Wine has more applications than just installing programs. I have tried using WINE to install drivers for a graphics card that i was having issues with. i just downloaded the driver and then ran it in WINE. When i was done, i just moved the newly installed/ Converted files to the drivers directory in the C drive.

Comment: This might work if he's only using the webcam in apps running under wine...

Comment: From the [wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8021e00ae87d4fbfb607739af82bdb621b9d9366)

Comment: No, i have literally done this without running the application under WINE. i have done this for graphics cards, Keyboards, mouse, webcams an what not. WINE just reads and converts the windows application to support what ever linux distro you wish to use. what you are looking for is to convert the EXE installation to ubuntu, in this case, to install drivers for a particular device.